# Искать слова, кроме определённых

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Например, я хочу найти/подсчитать в ноутпаде все слова, кроме собак.

```
\w+([^(dog)]|[^(dogs)])
```

Как между 2 выражениями поставить И?

Решение:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?<!dog)\b(?<!dogs)
```

Comment: Добавил описание ответа для разъяснений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такое регулярное выражение надо использовать: `\b([a-z0-9]+)\b(?<!dog|dogs)`. Объяснение:

1. `\b` - границы слов
2. `(...)` - группа
3. `[a-z0-9]` - допустимые символы
4. `+` - один или несколько символов
5. `(?<!...)` - гарантирует, что данный шаблон не будет совпадать и заканчиваться на текущей позиции в выражении
6. `dog|dogs` - исключающие слова, где `|` - или

Comment: Большое спасибо, открыл для себя \b.
\b(\w+)\b(?<!dog)\b(?<!dogs)

Comment: @Властелин я когда о нем узнал, то жизнь стала проще)

Comment: @Властелин: жаль, что некоторые фичи работают только с латиницей. Ну и *lookbehind* до JS всё никак не доберётся :(

Answer (score 2):

Используйте границы слов и блок предварительного просмотра **вперёд**:

```js
\b(?!(?:dog|dogs)\b)\w+
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/66aSS1/1/).

*Подробности*

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?!` - начало блока предварительного просмотра

  - `(?:dog|dogs)` - либо `dog`, либо `dogs`
  - `\b` - граница слова
- `)` - конец блока предварительного просмотра
- `\w+` - один и более буквоцифровых символов или символов нижнего подчёркиания.

В [JavaScript границу слова](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64292005/regular-expression-to-match-hashtags-in-both-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-lan/64292611#64292611) можно заменить на `(?<!\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}*|[\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}])` / `(?![\p{Alphabetic}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}])`:

```js
/(?<!\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}*|[\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}])(?!(?:собака|пёс)(?![\p{Alphabetic}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]))[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]+/gu
```

Конечно, всё это лучше записатьв виде переменных:

```js
const lwb = String.raw`(?<!\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}*|[\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}])`;
const rwb = String.raw`(?![\p{Alphabetic}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}])`;
const uw = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const exceptions = ['собака', 'пёс'];
const regex = new RegExp(`${lwb}(?!(?:${exceptions.join('|')})${rwb})${uw}+`, "gui");
console.log('Собака, пёс, кот и горилла'.match(regex));
```