# Jquery + Regex + Cyrillic

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, кириллица

Хочу исключить предлоги из поискового запроса на английском и русском. Решил пойти путём исключения 3-х и менее букв в словах. Сервер на PHP 7.3, Unicode. Для английского нашёл вот такое решение:

```
inputVal = inputVal.replace(/(\b([A-z]{3})\b)/g, ' ');
inputVal = inputVal.replace(/(\b([A-z]{2})\b)/g, ' ');
inputVal = inputVal.replace(/(\b([A-z]{1})\b)/g, ' ');
```

... а более длинные предлоги исключу отдельно.

**Вопрос 1.** Как эти три строки превратить в одну для Jquery?

**Вопрос 2.** Regex \b не работает для unicode и/или кириллицы. Как это обойти, чтобы повторить такое же для кириллицы?

[Вот пример](https://regex101.com/r/GVik7G/1)

Comment: В `\b([A-z]{3})\b` ошибка, правильно писать `\b([A-Za-z]{3})\b`. Объединить в одно - `\b([A-Za-z]{1,3})\b`. Граница слова в JavaScript RegExp можно задать [вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255921/182013). Можно и просто с помощью Юникод-класса, `/(?<![\w\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}])[\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}a-zA-Z]{1,3}(?![\w\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}])/gu`.

Comment: Dziękuję Ci bardzo!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```js
/(?<![\w\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}])[\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}a-zA-Z]{1,3}(?![\w\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}])/gu
```

Если нужен шаблон для сред, не поддерживающих стандарт ECMAScript 2018 и новее, можно заменить `\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}` на `[\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2F]` (эквивалент `\p{Cyrillic}`):

```js
/(?:^|[^\w\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2F])([\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2Fa-zA-Z]{1,3})(?![\w\u0400-\u0484\u0487-\u052F\u1C80-\u1C88\u1D2B\u1D78\u2DE0-\u2DFF\uA640-\uA69F\uFE2E\uFE2F])/g
```

Это шаблон для посика совпадений, не для их замены. Нужное значение находится в первой подмаске.

**Подробности**

- `(?<![\w\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}])` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу перед текущей позицией есть английская или кириллическая буква, цифра или символ `_`
- `[\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}a-zA-Z]{1,3}` - от одной до трёх английских или кириллических букв
- `(?![\w\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}])` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции есть английская или кириллическая буква, цифра или символ `_`.
- `g` - найти все совпадения
- `u` - режим дополнительной поддержки шаблонов Юникода.